# How to update a table which doesn't have primary id column in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am dealing with legacy code and do not have access to the database. There is a table which does not have a primary id column.

I can find a record using `record = Model.find_or_initialize_by(listing_id: rating.pid, criteria_id: 33)`.

I can increment an attribute with `record.rating_count += 1` but when I try to save it with `record.save!`, it gives the error `TypeError: nil is not a symbol nor a string`.

I think this is because record does not have a primary id (key) but I am not sure why it doesn't update the record.

If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Have you determined what exactly is `nil`? It *could* be that `rating.pid` is what is `nil` and `listing_id` is required in order to `save`. Hard to say without seeing model code, etc. but I'd, at least, start by trying to determine what exactly is `nil`.

Comment: i have asked the company(maintaing the db) to make listing_id primary key. well, rating.pid is not nill, i have seen in the console and db. it have value 1445 andit exists in the db. when i try to save after increment than it shows error.

Comment: In your Rails model, are there any `validate(s)` that might be causing the problem (i.e., `validate_presence_of :some_field`)?

Comment: no, there is no validation.

Comment: and there is no attribute `nil`

Comment: Then it may, given the DB relations, etc., just be that you need a primary key (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568797/typeerror-nil-is-not-a-symbol)

Comment: sounds like you are right but can i update this record with some mysql syntax?

Comment: Yeah ... you'd need something to run raw SQL in (like Navicat or some similar program).

Answer (score 0):

I also received the error `TypeError: nil is not a symbol nor a string` when trying to update a model which has no id column (or other primary key I could use). I had to add one.

You can add a primary key retrospectively using a migration:

```
    add_column :people, :id, :primary_key
```